# expectUserResponse field being ignored

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm seeing a strange behavior. I send a basic card with some information but regardless the expectUserResponse json flag, the conversation is not closed in Google Assistant. How come? Is it a bug? Can someone confirm?

JSON that is returned that contains the card:

```
{
  "data": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": false,
      "systemIntent": {
        "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
      },
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Some text",
              "displayText": "Some text"
            }
          },
          {
            "basicCard": {
              "title": "A title",
              "formattedText": "A long text",
              "buttons": [
                {
                  "title": "Title button",
                  "openUrlAction": {
                    "url": "http://www.google.com"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(From https://plus.google.com/102582215848134314158/posts/PG3NbHG9dsr)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're specifying `systemIntent`. This indicates what system Intent should be *used to handle the response*.

But you don't want to handle a response, as you've tried to indicate with `"expectUserResponse": false`.

Given the conflicting information - it chooses to honor the `systemIntent` setting and waits for the response.

The solution is to remove the `systemIntent` section completely. In general, unless you're requesting permission or one of the other helper Intents, you can leave this section out anyway since you're using API.AI.